# Merge video images with FFMPEG Library Android error

Tags: android, kotlin, android-ffmpeg

I using ffmpeg android library for marge watermark & video. I am facing the issue again and again. Mention below:

> 2023-04-08 14:05:02.892 20450-20637/com.projectname E/FFmpeg:
> Exception while trying to run: [Ljava.lang.String;@bc435e7
> java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/data/user/0/com.projectname/files/ffmpeg": error=13, Permission
> denied
> at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1050)
> at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:694)
> at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:559)
> at com.github.hiteshsondhi88.libffmpeg.ShellCommand.run(ShellCommand.java:10)
> at com.github.hiteshsondhi88.libffmpeg.FFmpegExecuteAsyncTask.doInBackground(FFmpegExecuteAsyncTask.java:38)
> at com.github.hiteshsondhi88.libffmpeg.FFmpegExecuteAsyncTask.doInBackground(FFmpegExecuteAsyncTask.java:10)
> at android.os.AsyncTask$3.call(AsyncTask.java:394)
> at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
> at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:305)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:920)
> Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=13, Permission denied
> at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
> at java.lang.UNIXProcess.(UNIXProcess.java:133)
> at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:141)
> at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
> at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:694) 
> at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:559) 
> at com.github.hiteshsondhi88.libffmpeg.ShellCommand.run(ShellCommand.java:10) 
> at com.github.hiteshsondhi88.libffmpeg.FFmpegExecuteAsyncTask.doInBackground(FFmpegExecuteAsyncTask.java:38) 
> at com.github.hiteshsondhi88.libffmpeg.FFmpegExecuteAsyncTask.doInBackground(FFmpegExecuteAsyncTask.java:10) 
> at android.os.AsyncTask$3.call(AsyncTask.java:394) 
> at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) 
> at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:305) 
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167) 
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) 
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:920)

```
  val file = File(
            Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                .toString() + File.separator + ""
                    + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".png"
        )
        try {
            file.createNewFile()
            val saveSettings: SaveSettings = SaveSettings.Builder()
                .setClearViewsEnabled(true)
                .setTransparencyEnabled(false)
                .build()
            mPhotoEditor?.saveAsFile(file.absolutePath, saveSettings, object : PhotoEditor.OnSaveListener {
                override fun onSuccess(@NonNull imagePath: String) {
                    this@CheckUploadedVideoFragment.imagePath = imagePath
                    binding.ivImage.source.setImageURI(Uri.fromFile(File(imagePath)))
                    
  val output = File((Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + File.separator + "" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".mp4"))

        try {
            output.createNewFile()

            exeCmd?.apply {
                add("-y")
                add("-i")
                add(videoPath)
                add("-i")
                add(imagePath)
                add("-filter_complex")
                add("[1:v]scale=$DRAW_CANVASW:$DRAW_CANVASH[ovrl];[0:v][ovrl]overlay=x=0:y=0")
                add("-c:v")
                add("libx264")
                add("-preset")
                add("ultrafast")
                add(output.absolutePath)
            }
            newCommand = arrayOfNulls(exeCmd?.size!!)
            for (j in exeCmd!!.indices) {
                newCommand[j] = exeCmd!![j]
            }

            executeCommand(newCommand, output.absolutePath)
        } catch (e: java.lang.Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }

                }

                override fun onFailure(exception: Exception) {
                    Toast.makeText(
                        requireContext(),
                        "Saving Failed...",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                    ).show()
                }
            })
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
```

```
private fun executeCommand(command: Array<String?>?, absolutePath: String?) {
        try {
            fFmpeg?.execute(command, object : FFmpegExecuteResponseHandler {
                override fun onSuccess(s: String) {
                    Log.d("CommandExecute", "onSuccess  $s")
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    //todo when Command executing successfully run then navigate next page
                }

                override fun onProgress(s: String) {
                    progressDialog?.setMessage(s)
                    Log.d("CommandExecute", "onProgress  $s")
                }

                override fun onFailure(s: String) {
                    Log.d("CommandExecute", "onFailure  $s")
                    progressDialog?.hide()
                }

                override fun onStart() {
                    progressDialog?.setTitle("Precessing")
                    progressDialog?.setMessage("Starting")
                    progressDialog?.show()
                }

                override fun onFinish() {
                    progressDialog?.hide()
                }
            })
        } catch (e: FFmpegCommandAlreadyRunningException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
```

How can I solve the issue?